# any open-source tools to compare xml with database rows?

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle, comparison

Are there any fully-functional open-source tools available to compare 1 xml fragment with 1 row in a database (better if it could handle multiple xmls and multiple rows but I would settle for just 1)?

For example,
if you had this xml:

```
<client>
<name>bob</name>
<age>47</age>
<UniqueNo>7632</UniqueNo>
</client>
```

and this database (oracle) row:

```
client_no           age          name
----------        -------        ------
7632                 47           bob
```

Is there a tool where you could specify which database columns map to which xml tags? Then it would output any matches and mismatches between the xml and the database row.

Comment: Might be a bit tricky, since XML is inherently hierarchical (nodes can contain nodes and those again more nodes), while a database row is "flat", e.g. it's just a flat list of columns and their values....

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something very much like this with SoapUI Pro right now.

With SoapUI, I send a Web request that should put data in a database table.

Then (again through SoapUI) I query the database and do asserts on the results, which when returned through SoapUI are in an XML format.

If I wanted to, I could set up SoapUI to compare the content of individual nodes in the Web service request/response to content in nodes in the database query result set.

There is a free version of SoapUI available at http://www.soapui.org/. I'm not positive that all the features you need are in the free version but it's worth a try. As long as you have the capability to use a JDBC request step (or a JDBC datasource step) and can put assertions on those steps, you should be in business.